# Feature Normalization/Standardization before or after Feature Selection?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, normalization, standardization

Should the process of feature normalization/standardization be done before or after the feature selection process?

Answer (score 6):

Before.

In fact, it's the "feature selection process" you mention that is pretty much *the* reason why you want to have your features standardized in the first place.

Comment: To elaborate: If you do not normalize / standardise your features - how would you compare them? Especially if one measures apples and the other one oranges.

Comment: In differential expression studies it is not uncommon to filter out (i.e. a form of feature selection) variables with very low variance/IQR/... If you standardize them to have unit variance before, this filtering of course makes no sense. So a plain "before" may not be correct.